# Laravel select all users that don't have a record

Tags: php, laravel

## The Issue

I want to get all users who are not managers of a company.

### The Relationships

I have a User model, that can have one CompanyGroup. The CompanyGroup can have many Managers. Managers can manage different types of entity, not just CompanyGroups, so this is a polymorphic relationship (however, not directly relevant to my question).

#### User Model

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CompanyGroup', 'company_group_id');
}
```

#### Company Group

```
public function managers()
{
    // This is polymorphic, as a manager can manage different types of entity.
    return $this->morphMany('App\Manager', 'managable');
}
```

#### Manager

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_uuid', 'uuid');
}
```

### What i've tried:

```
// Get all users, with a relationship of 'group', and the group's 'managers'
$users = $this->user->whereHas('group.managers', function($query)use($group)    
{
    // Exclude any users where the user's UUID is present in the managers table
    $query->where('exp_members.uuid', '!=', 'managers.user_uuid');
    })->get();
```

### What this produced

Nothing! It didn't list any users at all. The managers table is currently empty, so it should return all users that have the $group->id assigned to them. If i enter a random record in the managers table, it returns all of the users that have the group id assigned to them, but it doesn't filter out those who are managers.

Comment: Try `whereDoesntHave` instead, and change the `!=` to `=`. Also, you don't need to `use ($group)` unless you're going to use it within the closure. Actually, you mean even get away with `User::whereDoesntHave('group.managers')->get();`, though I doubt that.

Comment: The users will always have a group though, so I want to get the users and their group, but just not those users who are set as a manager of the group

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood. That sounds a bit more complicated, then.